# Converting Char array to TimeStamp in C++

Tags: c++

I have `char start_time[40] = "2020-04-01 12:00:00";` How can I convert the char array to timestamp in C++ without using `strptime`?

Comment: You could try [std::get_time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time)

Comment: what is the reason not to use strptime?

Comment: strptime does not work in my machine and I cant port any code to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
   const char T[] = "2020-04-01 12:00:00";
  
   time_t result = 0;
  
   int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0, hour = 0, min = 0,sec=0;
  
   if (sscanf(T, "%4d-%2d-%2d %2d:%2d:%2d", &year, &month, &day, &hour, &min,&sec) == 6) {
       struct tm test_time = {0};
       test_time.tm_year = year - 1900; /* years since 1900 */
       test_time.tm_mon = month - 1;
       test_time.tm_mday = day;
       test_time.tm_hour = hour;
       test_time.tm_min = min;
       test_time.tm_sec = sec;

       if ((result = mktime(&test_time)) == (time_t)-1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert time to time_t\n");
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
       } 
       std::cout << result << '\n' ;
       puts(ctime(&result));
       
       struct tm *t_start = localtime(&result);
       char date_time[30];
       strftime( date_time, sizeof(date_time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", t_start );
       std::cout << date_time << '\n' ;
       
       
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   else {
      fprintf(stderr, "The input was not a valid time format\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
}
```